# git rm -r --cached does not work

Tags: android, git, version-control

After running this command on build directories I want not to be checked anymore, and adding those directories to .gitignore, `git status` still gives me:

WordPressEditor/build/
build/
emoticon/build/

Why is that? How can I have a clean directory after running e.g.:

```
git rm -r --cached build
```

My .gitignore file content:

```
# My rules 
./build
./emoticon/build
./WordPressEditor/build
.gradle
.idea
```

Comment: Exactly: `./build` won't work in a `.gitignore`. `build/` will. My answer stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again with:

```
git rm -r --cached WordPressEditor/build/
git rm -r --cached build/
git rm -r --cached emoticon/build/
```

And make sure your `.gitignore` does include `build/`, not just `build`.
`build` would only ignore *files* named `build`.

Comment: OK, but after doing this, running `git add .` again seems to add everything anew! What can I do?

Comment: @JasonStack `git add .` won't add everything if your `.gitignore` is correct (meaning it has a `build/`, with a trailing slash, and no `./` prefix)

Comment: Oh I fixed the ending part by adding `/` but did not touch the beginning. Thanks

Comment: Lol. Right. Done!